# My script doesn't activate UI and doesn't play animations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Hey guys I have a made two scripts to handle door opening.
Script 1 - Raycast
Script 2 - The door opening script

I have the raycast on the player camera and I have script 2 on the door.

But there is a problem.

In script 2, I have code that makes UI active and inactive and code that does the door animation

SCRIPT 1 -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera FPScam;
    public float range = 6;
    public static float ToTarget; 


    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit Hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(FPScam.transform.position, FPScam.transform.forward, out Hit, range))
        {
            ToTarget = Hit.distance;
        }
    }
}
```

SCRIPT 2 -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Distance;
    public GameObject key;
    public GameObject reason;
    public GameObject Hinge;
    public AudioSource DoorCreak;
    
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Distance = PlayerCasting.ToTarget;
    }

    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Distance <= 3.5f)
        {
            key.SetActive(true);
            reason.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
        {
            if (Distance <= 3.5f)
            {
                key.SetActive(false);
                reason.SetActive(false);
                this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                Hinge.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("DoorOpenAnim");
                DoorCreak.Play();
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        key.SetActive(false);
        reason.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

But, the UI doesn't activate nor does the animation plays when I click 'E' **and** when the Raycast distance <= 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the raycast on the player camera

Since you're using `OnMouseOver()` and `OnMouseExit()` your methods will only work when the player's mouse is on the thing you want to raycast.

Make sure that the raycast is actually pointing the same direction the mouse cursor is. You use use `Debug.Raycast()` to visually see where the raycast is going.

If the raycast is going in the direction you want it to and it's still not working try a different way of communicating through the scripts and avoid using `OnMouseOver()`.

For example you could try something like this:

```cs
public class PlayerCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera FPScam;
    public float range = 6;
    public static float ToTarget = 0f;
    public static GameObject HoveredObject = null; // <----

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit Hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(FPScam.transform.position, FPScam.transform.forward, out Hit, range))
        {
            ToTarget = Hit.distance;
            HoveredObject = Hit.collider.gameObject; // <----
        }
    }
}
public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Distance;
    public GameObject key;
    public GameObject reason;
    public GameObject Hinge;
    public AudioSource DoorCreak;



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (PlayerCasting.HoveredObject == gameObject)
        {
            Distance = PlayerCasting.ToTarget;

            CheckDistance();
        }

    }

    private void CheckDistance()
    {
        if (Distance <= 3.5f)
        {
            key.SetActive(true);
            reason.SetActive(true);

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
            {
                key.SetActive(false);
                reason.SetActive(false);
                this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                Hinge.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("DoorOpenAnim");
                DoorCreak.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            key.SetActive(false);
            reason.SetActive(false);
        }


    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        key.SetActive(false);
        reason.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```